What's the simplest way to annotate a function/method parameter to accept an overlapping Union of types?
In all my functions that allow an overlapping union of types, I already have special handling that checks all parameters to ensure that there are no types which don't support operations with each other.
In my specific use-case, I'm writing functions that accept any of int, float, fractions.Fraction, and decimal.Decimal as input arguments, and since decimal.Decimal only supports mathematical operations with instances of itself and int, I wrote a function that implements the afore-mentioned special handling by first checking if there's any argument which is a decimal.Decimal object. And if there is, then the function re-scans all arguments to confirm that all of them are either decimal.Decimal or int. If it finds a violation, then it returns False to notify the caller that incompatible arguments are present (else it returns True). Below are the two functions that implement this check. All my functions & methods call the latter in a guard-clause at some point, and raise a TypeError if the return value is False:
from fractions import Fraction
import collections.abc
import decimal as dec
import typing as tp
Real = tp.Union[int, float, Fraction]
DecLike = tp.Union[int, dec.Decimal]


def _check_has_decimals(args: tp.Tuple[tp.Any, ...]) -> collections.abc.Iterator[bool]:
    """
    Returns an iterator yielding whether each argument is an instance of 'decimal.Decimal'.
    Can be passed to 'any()'.
    """
    return map(lambda param: isinstance(param, dec.Decimal), args)


def _check_arg_types(
        *args: tp.Any,
        has_decimals: tp.Union[tp.Callable[[tp.Tuple[tp.Any, ...]],
                                           collections.abc.Iterator[bool]],
                               bool] = _check_has_decimals
        ) -> bool:
    """Returns a boolean indicating if the types of the arguments are valid."""
    if not isinstance(has_decimals, bool):
        # Expand iterator to a simple 'bool'.
        has_decimals = any(has_decimals(args))
    if has_decimals:
        return all(map(lambda param: isinstance(param, tp.get_args(DecLike)), args))
    else:
        return all(map(lambda param: isinstance(param, tp.get_args(Real)), args))

The reason for the callable default argument is so if I'm writing a class that accepts mixed arguments, it can manually call _check_has_decimals and store the result as an instance attribute so that when any of its methods are called, it can supply _check_arg_types with the pre-computed value instead of letting the function re-compute it every time. But if being called from a function, then that function just calls _check_arg_types without the optional argument, as the same set of arguments will only have to be checked once anyway.
So in a function, for example, I would do this:
def add_stuff(a, b, c, d):
    if not _check_arg_types(a, b, c, d):
        err_msg = ("argument types other than 'int' or 'Decimal' aren't allowed if "
                   "any argument is a 'Decimal'!")
        raise TypeError(err_msg)
    return a + b + c + d

And now the problem. I can't get the type checker (PyRight in my case) to understand that I'm preventing the imcompatible types from collisioning in my code! If I simply annotate the above function's signature as:
Numeric = tp.Union[Real, DecLike]


def add_stuff(a: Numeric, b: Numeric, c: Numeric, d: Numeric) -> Numeric:
    ...

...then the nested union just gets flattened to tp.Union[int, float, Fraction, dec.Decimal], and when I type-check the code, I would get an error on the line return a + b because the type-checker thinks it's possible for... say a to be float and b to be Decimal. And nothing I do can make it understand better. The only solution seems to be to not type annotate any the function/methods in my code that accept overlapping unions, and lose the benefit of static type-checking completely (for those function/method/classes, at least).
And here is the list of things I've tried, with help from the Python chatroom. None of them work completely for my use-case:

Over-loading a function 2 times, with the first signature's parameter only accepting Reals and with return type annotated as Real, and the second signature with everything swapped out for DecLike. Also, make Real and DecLike generic types instead of Unions. It works if you suppress the overload-overlap error on the line of the first overload:
Real = tp.TypeVar("Real", bound=tp.Union[int, float, Fraction])
DecLike = tp.TypeVar("DecLike", bound=tp.Union[int, dec.Decimal])


@tp.overload
def add_stuff(a: Real, b: Real) -> Real:  # type: ignore[overload-overlap]
    ...


@tp.overload
def add_stuff(a: DecLike, b: DecLike) -> DecLike:
    ...


def add_stuff(a, b):
    return a + b


print(tp.reveal_type(add_stuff(1, 1)))
print(tp.reveal_type(add_stuff(1, 1.5)))
print(tp.reveal_type(add_stuff(Fraction(1, 2), 0.5)))
print(tp.reveal_type(add_stuff(3, dec.Decimal("0.5"))))
print(tp.reveal_type(add_stuff(dec.Decimal("1"), dec.Decimal("1"))))

But the problem with this is that it doesn't work for class instance methods which don't take any arguments and return a value based on an instance attribute. If I tried to define, say:
class Foo:
    ...

    @tp.overload
    def return_something(self) -> Real:
        ...

    @tp.overload
    def return_something(self) -> DecLike:
        ...

    def return_something(self):
        return self.some_instance_attribute

then it would trigger the error A function returning TypeVar should receive at least one argument containing the same TypeVar [type-var].

Make the class which supports overlapping unions a generic class, and then create an overloaded helper function which take constructor arguments, use them unchanged to create a new instance of the class, and has its return type annotated as a subscription of the generic class.
T = tp.TypeVar("T")
TReal = tp.TypeVar("TReal", bound=tp.Union[int, float, Fraction])
TDec = tp.TypeVar("TDec", bound=tp.Union[int, dec.Decimal])


class C(tp.Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, foo: T, bar: T) -> None:
        self.foo, self.bar = foo, bar

    def return_something(self) -> T:
        return self.foo + self.bar


@tp.overload
def from_number(a: TReal, b: TReal) -> C[TReal]:
    ...


@tp.overload
def from_number(a: TDec, b: TDec) -> C[TDec]:
    ...


def from_number(a, b):
    return C(a, b)


print(tp.reveal_type(from_number(1, 1)))
print(tp.reveal_type(from_number(1, 1.5)))
print(tp.reveal_type(from_number(Fraction(1, 2), 0.5)))
print(tp.reveal_type(from_number(3, dec.Decimal("0.5"))))
print(tp.reveal_type(from_number(dec.Decimal("1"), dec.Decimal("1"))))

This gives an Operator "X" not supported for types "T@C" and "T@C" whenever I try to do any operations on the stored instance attributes. So this is basically the same as just annotating as tp.Union[int, float, Fraction, dec.Decimal] in that I have to add a # type: ignore[reportOperatorIssue] after every operation between the arguments.


Is there any solution (preferably simple) that actually works for my use case? Or am I trying to do something impossible?

Your _check_arg_types() looks weird. If you don't intend to pass any callables other than _check_has_decimals, the signature can be simplified to just (*args: Any, has_decimals: bool = True).

@InSync Alright, I could hard-code the call to _check_has_decimals inside _check_arg_types, but the signature would have to be (*args: Any, has_decimals: Optional[bool] = None), because otherwise I won't be able to tell if the caller actually has no decimals or if it wants the default detection function to be called. Also, that doesn't fix the problem of how to type-annotate my functions and methods which accepts either Union[int, float, Fraction] or Union[int, Decimal].

Here's my attempt that got closest to working so far. But it fails if you change the type alias DecLike on line 5 from decimal.Decimal to typing.Union[decimal.Decimal, int].
